# Ringoid over symmetric group? (part 2)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, symmetric-groups, division-ring

[Last time,](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3336478/480135) it turned out that there is a near-ring whose domain and additive operation is that of symmetric groups.

What if the operation is taken as multiplicative instead? Could it be a skew field? Or just a ring?

Comment: A finite division ring is a field, so it can't have the multiplicative structure of the symmetric group.

Comment: IIRC there is a near-field with multiplicative operation that of $SL_2(\Bbb{F}_5)$, which, alas, is not quite $S_5$ even though it shares the composition factors with it (one of the very few finite near-fields with a non-solvable multiplicative structure). A similar recollection is that either $SL_2(\Bbb{F}_3)$ or $GL_2(\Bbb{F}_3)$ appears (these all have order $p^2-1$ for a prime $p$). But the same problem appears: $SL_2(\Bbb{F}_3)$ has $A_4$ as a quotient, but a non-trivial center. I would need to dig up old papers by Zassenhaus to check the details.